# R insert a row by comparing two dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame with two columns (language, articles) as column headers, and then I have another dataframe with column headers being language and count.

I want to iterate over first dataframe and if the value in the language column of first dataframe matches the value of the language column in second dataframe. I want to insert the value of articles column to the second dataframe.

```
  language articles
1       en  4200596
2       de  1571581
3       fr  1369891
4       nl  1405514
5       it  1020971
6       es   981124

  language count numArticles
1       gv    86          NA
2      sco     3          NA
3      zea    19          NA
4      szl     0          NA
5      pnb     2          NA
6      cdo    28          NA
```

I accomplished it by writing a loop but I am sure this is not the best way to do it or may be there is R way of doing this in much cleaner and a faster way:

```
for(i in 1:numberOfElements) {
  for(k in 1:numberOfElements) {
    if (as.character(wiki.template.count$language[i]) == as.character(wiki.lang.codes.size$language[k])) {
      wiki.template.count$numArticles[i] <- wiki.lang.codes.size$articles[k]
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to merge two data.frames. Use `merge`.

```
merge(wiki.template.count, wiki.lang.codes.size, by = 'language')
```

Comment: yes but the language data column is not in same order, i mean the order of dataframe1 doesn't match dataframe2

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis -- this will create a new data.frame, you may need to set `all=TRUE` (or some variant) to get the style of join you wish. It will take care of the ordering for you.

Comment: if i want to sort by new column can I do that at the sametime?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `merge` if the column names are the same.

Suppose you have 2 data frames `df1` and `df2` both with column `language` this should work

```
df_merge <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'language')
```

if you want to preserve the order of df2 instead of df1 then switch them in the merge

```
df_merge <- merge(df2, df1, by = 'language')
```